# Run Bash script as root in startup on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bash, ubuntu-18.04

I wanted to run a bash script as root in startup. First I started using RC.Local and Crontab but nothing works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create the service file as in the template below and add the file in the location  `/etc/systemd/system/`

And the Template as

```
[Unit]
Description = ~Name of the service~

[Service]
WorkingDirectory= ~directory of working file~
ExecStart= ~directory~/filename.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Start the service file by the name using

```
systemctl start servicefile.service
```

To enable on startup

```
systemctl enable servicefile.service
```

To check the status

```
systemctl status servicefile.service
```

To stop

```
systemctl stop servicefile.service
```

Answer (score 6):

Create a systemd unit file in /etc/systemd/system/ and use it to execute your script. (i.e. `hello-world.service`).

```
[Unit]
Description=Hello world
After=sysinit.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
User=root
ExecStart=/bin/echo hello world
ExecStop=/bin/echo goodby world

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now you can use it through `systemctl` as you would with other services.

```
$ systemctl enable hello-world
$ systemctl start hello-world
$ systemctl stop hello-world
$ systemctl status hello-world
● hello-world.service - Hello world
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/hello-world.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2019-10-09 13:54:58 CEST; 1min 47s ago
  Process: 11864 ExecStop=/bin/echo goodby world (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 11842 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 09 13:54:38 lnxclnt1705 systemd[1]: Started Hello world.
Oct 09 13:54:38 lnxclnt1705 echo[11842]: hello world
Oct 09 13:54:57 lnxclnt1705 systemd[1]: Stopping Hello world...
Oct 09 13:54:57 lnxclnt1705 echo[11864]: goodby world
Oct 09 13:54:58 lnxclnt1705 systemd[1]: Stopped Hello world.
```

Make sure that you use the full path to your script in the unit file (i.e. /bin/echo). Check out the documentation about keys used in `hello-world.service`:

- [[Unit]](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)
- [[Service]](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)

Comment: i followed your code but is not working. I enabled the service also. Am run ubuntu in vmware so is it problem??

Comment: I've updated my answer and tested it. The symlink wasn't necessary on my laptop. Make sure that you add the /full/path/to/your/script.sh in the unit file. I hope it works now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Place the script inside /etc/init.d

Ensure that it has the extension '.sh'

Answer (score 0):

For the crontab,

there is difference in if you set up user crontab or root crontab:

```
$ crontab -e 

@reboot sudo ...
```

^^ This is user's cron tab and wont work as it is.

```
$ sudo crontab -e

@reboot ...
```

^^ This is root's cron tab and will run comand as root.

The `@reboot` should do the trick for you of running scripts after startup.